# Could I combine these two functions and get the same output?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two functions for extracting latitude and longitude from a string. I am then creating a new column for both in my df. I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to combine the two functions, and use the combined one for both new columns.

```
import re
def coordinates_lat(string):
    coords = re.findall("\(.+\)", string)
    lat , long = coords[0].split(',')
    return float(lat.replace('(', ''))

def coordinates_long(string):
    coords = re.findall("\(.+\)", string)
    lat , long = coords[0].split(',')
    return float(long.replace(')',''))


data['hs_directory']['lat'] = data['hs_directory']['Location 1'].apply(coordinates_lat)
data['hs_directory']['lon'] = data['hs_directory']['Location 1'].apply(coordinates_long)
```

This is how I tried to combine:

```
def coordinates(string, lat_or_long):
    coords = re.findall("\(.+\)", string)
    lat , long = coords[0].split(',')
    if lat_or_long == 'lat':
        return float(lat.replace('(', ''))
    if lat_or_long == 'long':
        return float(long.replace(')',''))

data['hs_directory']['lat'] = data['hs_directory']['Location 1'].apply(coordinates, 'lat')
```

It says I am missing an argument for 'lat_or_long'.

Comment: Try `from functools import partial; apply(partial(coordinates, lat_or_long="lat"))`.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, realized you need to let python know explicitly the second variable is for 'lat_or_long'

```
data['hs_directory']['lat'] = data['hs_directory']['Location 1'].apply(coordinates, lat_or_long = 'lat')
```

Comment: Consider editing your answer to more explicitly show what you did to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Pass 'lat' as the keyword argument and that will solve the problem:

```
data['hs_directory']['lat'] = data['hs_directory']['Location 1'].apply(coordinates, lat_or_long='lat')
```